How to calculate stats for a custom Pokemon sprite
I'm working on a hobby project where I want to create custom Pokemon sprites and integrate them into a basic Pokemon-style battling system. I've drawn the sprites but I'm not sure how to calculate things like their base stats, types, moves, etc.
In the main series games, Pokemon have base stats for things like attack, defense, special attack, etc. These stats then get modified by factors like levels, individual values (IVs), natures, etc. to determine a Pokemon's actual stats.
How would I go about calculating reasonable base stats for a custom Pokemon? Are there any common formulas or approaches game designers use? I also need to assign types, moves, abilities - is there a general guideline for balancing types and making sure moves are properly STABbed?
Any advice on algorithmically determining these underlying stats and attributes for a custom Pokemon would be greatly appreciated. I want to make sure my creations will be balanced and fun to battle with.
For calculating base stats, I initially tried just randomly assigning numbers between 50-100 to all standard base stats (HP, Attack, Defense etc.).
However, this likely wouldn't result in well balanced Pokemon. Some may end up with way higher stats than others without considering things like type effectiveness.
For types, I assigned them randomly without considering type matchups or weaknesses/resistances. This again would make for poorly balanced battles.
For moves, I generated random move names but didn't assign types or base power. So the moves wouldn't benefit from STAB or have appropriate strengths/weaknesses.
Overall, I was expecting to need some kind of guidelines or formulas to produce Pokemon with thoughtful, balanced base stats, types, moves and abilities based on factors like:
Stat totals that fit the Pokemon's type/ability
Effective type matchups and weaknesses
STAB for moves matching a Pokemon's type
Appropriate base power and PP for moves
But I wasn't sure what approaches game designers use behind the scenes. Any tips on algorthms or common practices would be greatly appreciated.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
